# Saving image into server to get url later

Tags: php

I have this on one page:

```
<form method="POST" action="getdata.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

And here is getdata.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require "connection.php";


 //connect to database
$file=$_FILES['image']['name'];
$file_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


$path="Libraries\Pictures".$file;

if(file_exists($path))
{
 chmod($path,0755);
  unlink($path);
}

if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path))
{
   echo "File uploaded succesfully";

}
else {
    echo "no";
}
```

I get these errors:

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(Libraries\Pictures2.png): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpnAKn2A' to 'Libraries\Pictures2.png'
```

How can I fix these so the url will be stored in my database for easy access later

Comment: `$path="Libraries\Pictures".$file;` is (probably) missing a slash here if `Pictures` is a folder (which seems likely), `$path="Libraries/Pictures/".$file;` and make sure that folder can be written to.

Comment: when I added a / I got this : 
`Warning: move_uploaded_file(Libraries\Pictures/2.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: when I do a \ slash, it gives me a whole code error.

Comment: check folder names and permissions then

Comment: The permissions in all the folders are all allow. @fre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want the image or the url of the image?
Your code will give you neither image nor url, if you want to save URLs you need a database to store them there, and if you want to upload image from url this is another story you must use those two functions:

```
file_put_contents
file_get_contents
```

some errors to correct:

```
$path ='/Libraries/Pictures';
// without $file
// in place of 
$path="Libraries\Pictures".$file;
```

I hope I helped you